# Vertically Center <p> within scroll up animation

Tags: html, css

I am probably not the first person in the world to have a mouse-over scroll up text animation, however, at the same time, for whatever reason, I have found next to none in terms of analogs to compare with. My particular set up uses `<figure>` wrapped over `<figcaption>` wrapped over sibling `<p>`'s.

The issue I'm having with my CSS is my `<p>`'s are not centered very well vertically after the animation completes.. That is to say, depending on how long the text inside `<p>` there will either be too much space above or below the list of `<p>`'s. Have a look at my snippet. I want the space within the figure (inside the black border) to be equal at the top and bottom, but it's not:

```css
figure img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

figure {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-right: -40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

figure figcaption {
  padding: 2em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

figure figcaption::before,
figure figcaption::after {
  pointer-events: none;
}

figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

figure p {
  font-family: Play;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: -110%;
}

figure:hover h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, transform 0.95s;
}

figcaption:hover p:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition: 1s;
  bottom: 60%;
  opacity: 1;
}

figcaption:hover p:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: 60%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

figcaption:hover p:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 60%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: .6s;
}

figure:hover .border-rect {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

figure.effect img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

figure.effect figcaption::before,
figure.effect figcaption::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
}

figure.effect figcaption::before {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
}

figure.effect figcaption::after {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform: scale(1, 0);
}

figure.effect h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, transform 0.95s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  padding-top: 30%;
}

figure.effect:hover figcaption::before,
figure.effect:hover figcaption::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

figure:hover h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<figure class="effect">
  <img src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain#/media/File:Lewis_overthrust_fault_nh10f.jpg" />
  <figcaption>
    <h2>Hover Somewhere Around Here</h2>
    <p>paragraph paragraph paragraph </p>
    <p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
    <a href="#">View more</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**Question:** How do I have my `<p>` scroll robust to different lengths of text the `<p>` could have? Equivalently, how do I ensure my `<p>`'s scroll up and land centered vertically within the figure (the black border in the snippet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done a pretty decent job of this, can I just say first.

Regarding the centering issue, there's 32px padding on each side, so if you give the paragraph a max-width of 236 (300 -64) then the paragraphs will center fine. I set it to 235 in the snippet but add the extra pixel if you want.. :)

The different lengths question.. hmm. It caters for paragraphs of different widths. If you want to cater paragraphs for indeterminable/varied lengths,  the image that you're using to create the outline will impede the potential visibility of a scrollbar if you added overflow. If I were to make a scroll-able box, I'd have probably started with a bordered div instead of a figure .. this may be an alternative route for you to take? Just a suggestion.

```css
figure img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

figure h2 {
  max-width: 235px;
}

figure {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-right: -40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

figure figcaption {
  padding: 2em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

figure figcaption::before,
figure figcaption::after {
  pointer-events: none;
}

figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

figure p {
  font-family: Play;
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 235px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: -110%;
}

figure:hover h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, transform 0.95s;
}

figcaption:hover p:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition: 1s;
  bottom: 70%;
  opacity: 1;
}

figcaption:hover p:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: 70%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

figcaption:hover p:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 70%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: .6s;
}

figure:hover .border-rect {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

figure.effect img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

figure.effect figcaption::before,
figure.effect figcaption::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
}

figure.effect figcaption::before {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
}

figure.effect figcaption::after {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform: scale(1, 0);
}

figure.effect h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, transform 0.95s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  padding-top: 30%;
  max-width:235px;
}

figure.effect:hover figcaption::before,
figure.effect:hover figcaption::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

figure:hover h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<figure class="effect">
  <img src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain#/media/File:Lewis_overthrust_fault_nh10f.jpg" />
  <figcaption>
    <h2>Hover Somewhere Around Here
    </h2>
    <p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph </p>
    <p>You hovered on me! Great!</p>
    <p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
    <a href="#">View more</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: An addendum to my earlier answer.. I retrieved these old jsfiddles from my library. You may find them useful. First one limits length of paragraph but adds a read more so that it's expandable, http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/x808vpn5/, 2nd is an expandable div http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/z1h7r7d6/1/ (combo of 1+2 would work?)  The 3rd is a textarea that expands as it's written in. http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/3tmdbtd6/. Good luck!

Comment: Excellent feedback, things are looking more optimistic now, thanks for that! I may not have worded it well in my post, but I'm mainly after the vertical centering (space above and below the `<p>`s). For example, if we have 3 very short sibling `<p>`s then there will be a lot of space left at the bottom (left and right will still be centered of course). Your fiddles got me thinking more, but I'm not sure if they can be brought to bear for vertical centering.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Yes, you couldn't centre vertically unless you knew exactly how long the text was. The 32px padding was on all sides though. Hope you got further with it, you're welcome for the other fiddles ...